# Loading Cassandra Extension in PHP running on HHVM on Apache

Tags: php, cassandra, hhvm

I have been trying to load the datastax cassandra php-driver on ubuntu (apache web server). I am also running php on hhvm. Now the problem is that I have installed the driver and I have the cassandra extension file located in  /usr/lib/php5/20131226/cassandra.so. I have also edited /etc/hhvm/php.ini file to contain:
hhvm.dynamic_extension_path = /usr/lib/php5/20131226
hhvm.dynamic_extensions[cassandra] = cassandra.so

And I have edited /etc/hhvm/server.ini to contain:
hhvm.enable_zend_compat = true.

Now when I start hhvm, I get the following error:
Uncaught exception: Could not open extension /usr/lib/php5/20131226/cassandra.so: /usr/lib/php5/20131226/cassandra.so: undefined symbol: zend_new_interned_string\n.

Could I please get help resolving this issue?

Comment: I am having the same problem. I think the extension has to be converted to a hhvm extension. See http://www.sklar.com/software/php/2015/05/07/converting-a-php-extension-to-hhvm/